# What is the meaning of register1:register2 in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, cpu-registers

What is the meaning of register1:register2 in assembly language.
For example `ax:bx`, then which type of address will be used in this instruction.
Obviously two registers AX and BX are involved in this situation, how do they contribute to make the outcome of the instruction?

I saw a code line like this:

```
add [es:di], ax
```

I tried to debug, but no results.

Comment: That usually means a larger unit formed from the two given registers. `ax:bx` would be a 32 bit integer with the top 16 bits in `ax` and the low 16 in `bx`. You don't use this in instructions explicitly. For example `MUL` produces result in `dx:ax` but that is implicit, you don't need to write it out.

Comment: There's no such thing as an assembly **language**. There are assembly **languages**. Tag the architecture you have in mind and possibly make a [mcve] so we can tell what you mean from the context.

Comment: https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/acegals.htm#protocol-registernames "Two or more register names can be given consecutively, separated by colons. This means the registers are appended to represent a larger variable. For example, `cs:ip` refers to a 32-bit (16-bit segment + 16-bit offset) far pointer, `dx:ax` refers to a 32-bit variable, and `dl:ax` refers to a 24-bit variable."

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  Can you give a specific example?

Comment: For example if given, mov ds, ax:bx, then ds will contain value of ax plus next paragraph+offset(value of bx). I think so, please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @AshokDavid `mov ds, ax:bx` is not a valid instruction! `ax:bx` is never used in any instruction. It is just a way to convey a meaning (the notion of a value larger than what a register can carry).

Comment: Where did you see an instruction with `ax:bx`? What was the full instruction?

Comment: I saw a code line like this: add [es:di], ax

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of register1:register2 in assembly language. For example `ax:bx`, then which type of address will be used in this instruction.

register1:register2 (eg. `ax:bx`) is never used in any instruction. It is never a valid instruction component, rather it is a way to convey a meaning: the notion of a value larger than what one register can carry.

> For example `ax:bx`, then which type of address will be used in this instruction. Obviously two registers AX and BX are involved in this situation, how they contribute to make the outcome of the instruction.

Please note that it need not stop at 2 registers.
It is always a combination of values, and the leftmost component is always considered the most-significant one.
Just *how* the individual values get combined varies.

### Using general purpose registers

Your example of `ax:bx` typically signifies a 32-bit value for which the reconstituting rule is `(ax * 65536) + bx`.
Another example could be `cl:bx:dx:ax` and that one would ordinarily represent a 56-bit value obeying the rule `(cl << 48) + (bx << 32) + (dx << 16) + ax`.

### Using special registers

If one of the registers is a segment register like in `ds:dx`, the reconstituting rule is different. It becomes `(ds << 4) + dx`, at least in the real address mode of the CPU. Operating in protected mode the combination `cs:eip` would reconstitute from adding the value in the EIP register to some base address found in a segment descriptor.

### Even more special

There's nothing that prevents you from coming up with your very own formats. So, you could invent a combination of a 16-bit integral value with a fractional part in the range [0,99], simply by defining a combo like `AX:BL`, just an example.

---

> I saw a code line like this:

> ```
> add [es:di], ax
> ```

This `es:di` is not at all like the `ax:bx` we talked about above!
Here the colon character does not really combine these two registers as was discussed before. The colon in this (valid) instruction is actually a terminating character for the [Segment Override Prefix](https://www.includehelp.com/embedded-system/segment-override-prefix-8086-microprocessor.aspx). In a MASM-style assembler you could write this instruction like: `add es:[di],ax`, and in NASM you could write this same instruction also as `es add [di],ax`. See how `es:` no longer sticks to the `di` part? The `[di]` that remains is just one of the available 16-bit effective address forms:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [BX + SI] | [BX + SI + disp8] | [BX + SI + disp16] |
| [BX + DI] | [BP + DI + disp8] | [BP + DI + disp16] |
| [BP + SI] | [BX + SI + disp8] | [BX + SI + disp16] |
| [BP + DI] | [BP + DI + disp8] | [BP + DI + disp16] |
| [SI] | [SI + disp8] | [SI + disp16] |
| [DI] | [DI + disp8] | [DI + disp16] |
| [disp16] | [BP + disp8] | [BP + disp16] |
| [BX] | [BX + disp8] | [BX + disp16] |

Answer (score 2):

In 16 bit real mode, [es:di] generates an address of (es<<4)+di. In Windows 3.1 16 bit 286 protected mode, `es` points to a 64KB block of memory, and di is an index into that block of memory, and adding 8 to `es` will advance `es` to the next 64KB block of memory. For recent versions of Windows, `gs` is used for unique per thread local variables, such as the seed value for rand().

Comment: In protected and long mode, segment registers are "selectors" for entries in the GDT or LDT (which contains a base address and limit).  In long mode, the base/limit is ignored for segments other than FS and GS.  Windows 3.1's setup is just one way to set up the GDT, and not how it works in 32-bit code.  In 64-bit code, setting a GS or FS base address is normally done by the OS (with `wrmsr` to set the base directly, not by writing the segment register itself.)  https://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation

Comment: One useful way to think about real vs. protected mode is that it just changes the semantics for how the segment base (and optionally limit) are set when you write a segment register.  *Using* a segment base, like `[es:bx]`, is always `es_base + bx` regardless of what mode you're currently in, so what matters is how the base was set, which might or might not correspond to what would happen if you did `push es` / `pop es`: https://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode

Comment: @PeterCordes - In case it wasn't obvious, I clarified Windows 3.1 286 protected mode to be 286 16 bit protected mode.  For Windows 3.1 32 bit mode, there is winmem32, a 32 bit flat model that only Watcom C|C++ compiler supports, and win32s, which is a 32 bit flat model with a subset of the Window NT API.

Comment: I commented because your answer didn't explain *why* segmentation works that way in 16-bit 286 protected mode, that it's something the OS had to set up tables for.  The hardware doesn't just work that way on its own.  Segmentation isn't a boatload of different special cases, it's always `linear = seg_base + offset` with a few different ways of setting `seg_base` depending on mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree that loading the segment base when writing to a segreg is the point where Real Address Mode and Protected Mode differ, rather moreso than an address dereference using a segment base. There are some other related differences; the biggest one is that in Protected Mode you can only load CS from a code descriptor and code descriptors can never be used to write to memory in Protected Mode. In Real/Virtual 86 Mode, CS is generally just as RWX as all segregs, as concerns segmentation.

Comment: @ecm: oh, interesting, I hadn't realized `mov [cs:esp], eax` would necessarily fault.  It does in a Linux executable where `mov [esp], eax` doesn't.  (In `_start` where `esp` points to read/write memory, and CS base = DS/ES/SS base = 0.  32-bit process under a 64-bit kernel, so no writing via the CS segment applies in 32-bit compat sub-mode of long mode as well, although not in 64-bit mode where a CS prefix has no effect at all.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah we (I) just talked about that recently on our DOS forum: https://www.bttr-software.de/forum/forum_entry.php?id=21394 (**ETA**: To be fair I should have qualified in that entry that I meant non-64-bit Protected Mode, I didn't know that CS overrides have no effect in Long Mode / in a 64-bit CS.)